# How to clear the Redis terminal?

Tags: redis, nosql

Does anyone know how to clear the Redis terminal ?
I am working on Windows OS, and tried to clear the Redis terminal by using: cls, clear, CTRL+L but nothing happens.
I appreciate your help.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you not just exit redis-cli clear the terminal view and then enter redis-cli again?

Comment: No , actually when I type clear to clear the terminal, Redis moves a line  down, it's like you hit enter

Comment: I tried it in Linux (Cent OS), 'clear' command clears the redis-cli terminal

Comment: Thank you, Ankit, I think it does work only on Linux and Mac OS.